# Less CSS mixin guard clause not working as expected

Tags: css, less

I have a mixin that I've developed to allow for responsive padding and margins.

The idea is allow for any permutation - for example,  I can declare just the @top, vertical sides with @vertical, or all (@all).

I first check to see if any individual properties have been declared, the vertical/horizontal, then all.

The code below DOESN'T work correctly. Here's the offending code:

```
& when not (@top = 0), (@right = 0), (@bottom = 0), (@left = 0) {
        .MakeFluidGutter(@top; @right; @bottom; @left);
    }
```

**It fails to correctly work out that I've declared 3 individual properties.**

I presume that the two other guard clauses beneath don't work either for the same reason.

Here's a quick fix:

```
& when (@top > 0), (@top < 0), (@right > 0), (@right < 0), (@bottom > 0), (@bottom < 0), (@left > 0), (@left < 0) {
    .MakeFluidGutter(@top; @right; @bottom; @left);
}
```

Here's how I call it:

```
   .FluidPadding(@right:1; @bottom:1; @left:1);
```

It's probably down to my interpretation but I know there are a couple of experts on here who will be able to guide me down the right path.

Talking of right paths - if there is a better way of achieving the `.FluidGutter()` functionality please let me know as I'm learning as I go.

---

Here's the complete code:

```
.FluidMargin(@top:0; @right:0; @bottom:0; @left:0; @vertical:0; @horizontal:0; @all:1) { 
    .FluidGutter(margin; @top; @right; @bottom; @left; @vertical; @horizontal; @all)    
}

.FluidPadding(@top:0; @right:0; @bottom:0; @left:0; @vertical:0; @horizontal:0; @all:1) { 
    .FluidGutter(padding; @top; @right; @bottom; @left; @vertical; @horizontal; @all)    
}

.FluidGutter(@property; @top; @right; @bottom; @left; @vertical; @horizontal; @all) when
     (@property = margin),
     (@property = padding) { 
    & when not (@top = 0), (@right = 0), (@bottom = 0), (@left = 0) {
        .MakeFluidGutter(@top; @right; @bottom; @left);
    }
    & when (@top = 0) and (@right = 0) and (@bottom = 0) and (@left = 0) and not (@vertical = 0), not (@horizontal = 0) {
        .MakeFluidGutter(@vertical; @horizontal; @vertical; @horizontal);
    }
    & when (@top = 0) and (@right = 0) and (@bottom = 0) and (@left = 0) and (@vertical = 0) and (@horizontal = 0) and not (@all = 0){
        .MakeFluidGutter(@all; @all; @all; @all);
    }

    .MakeFluidGutter(@top; @right; @bottom; @left) {
        .MakeGutter(@property; @arguments);
    }
}

.MakeGutter(@property; @arguments) when
     (@property = margin),
     (@property = padding) {

    .BuildGutter(@xSmallMargin);

    & when (@smallMargin > @xSmallMargin) {
        .SmallWindow({
            .BuildGutter(@smallMargin);
        });
    }
    & when (@mediumMargin > @smallMargin) {
        .MediumWindow({
            .BuildGutter(@mediumMargin);
        });
    }
    & when (@largeMargin > @mediumMargin) {
        .LargeWindow({
            .BuildGutter(@largeMargin);
        });
    }
    & when (@xLargeMargin > @largeMargin) {
        .XLargeWindow({
            .BuildGutter(@xLargeMargin);
        });
    }

    .BuildVertGutter(@size) {
        .-(top);
        .-(right);
        .-(bottom);
        .-(left);
        .-(@side) when not (@@side = 0) {
            @{property}-@{side}: (@size * @@side);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've actually spotted where I've gone wrong (missed multiple "not" from code), but I'd still appreciate any comments from the LESS experts.

Comment: Well yes, at first glance you simply missing `not` at each `or`ed condition. I.e. `not(a), (b)` is not equal to `not(a, b)`. (This may be confusing because it is different from how `not` works in media quires, but in Less they they decided a more canonical not-and-or behaviour where or/and have higher priority - otherwise it's just impossible to create many typical expressions... for that reason `or` instead of `,` is also recommended).

Comment: For the rest, well, you understand that for a complex snippet it takes time to understand what the code is actually doing to suggest some real tips (instead of useless line-per-line suggestions). Though at quick glance (if it was only about me) I'm afraid the code uses one of those "top-five-don'ts" I [aggressively fight against recently] so the very tip from me would be "rethink the *whole* approach from scratch" (not very helpful for you in the middle of development, right?) But otherwise it goes about tedious refactoring of some code snippet you don't find correct as a whole at all.

Comment: @seven-phases-max - thanks for your comments - what are the top 5 donts?

Comment: Either way another important tip is to think in mixin conditions instead of blind `if -> & when` translations, e.g. notice that your `FluidGutter` code can be rewritten as something like [this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/a31c62a25e31657f13d3bcfd33930025) (pseudo-code since I can't really test either). And there's a lot of room for the [`argument-pattern-matching`](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-pattern-matching) (always preferred over `when`, for instance you can match `all trlb = 0`) and [`default()`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-default).

Comment: *top-5-five don'ts* Well that's a story for big blog-post, but in your particular case it's for `SmallWindow/MediumWindow/LargeWindow/etc.` thing. See [#3050](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/3050) and the stuff linked there. I.e. it's hard to say w/o seeing all the code if it's really not reasonable in you particular case, but the fact that you need 4 different conditions to call 4 different mixins (that finally most likely do the very same thing just mapped to 4 different screen-size values) is quite suspicious.

Comment: Thanks for the tips - great clean code!

Comment: Getting back to `FluidGutter`, in non-pseudo code I'd write it like [this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/bf4c8ce5a3159af9eb5b82f48e554791) (yet again not sure if it's matches what you plan exactly, but it should give some tips).

Comment: On the other side, this mixin starts to look like the directly opposite case of the "mixin-name-vs.parameters" anti-pattern. I.e. it's not clear what we gain by encrypting the mixin behaviour into its parameters in this case, e.g. why can't `.FluidGutter(padding, @v: 22, @h: 33);` be replaced with `.FluidGutterVH(padding, 22 33);` considering the latter does not need any dreadful conditions (and both require some "vh" marker in either case).

Comment: Btw. I think you can post the answer about missing `not`s since it definitely is the answer for the initial problem. And the rest (i.e. conditionals optimization) is too general and too long to be posted (imho).

Comment: @JohnOhara You got 62 lines of code just for setting margin or padding? Writing `margin: 20px 15px` is much more readable then these tons of mixins.

Comment: @3rdthemagical - Not so. If you look at what the mixin does, it selectively creates margins for 5 different window sizes - thats 18 lines of code per usage - soon eats up the 62 lines of code.